# I want to create a downloadable and virtual product in WordPress (WooCommerce) with certain conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to create a downloadable and virtual product in WordPress (WooCommerce) that requires two or three fields (email, name and phone number) to purchase this product, so that after entering these values, the user can be directed to the payment page, and if The payment was successful. Based on these values (email, name and phone number), a downloadable text file (in the form of a download link) will be generated as below:

> thank you dear $name
> your phone number is $phone and your email is $email and your order number is $id_Or_ordernumber so you can download your file with $downloadlink this button!

And with each email it is possible to buy only once, that is, before it is directed to the payment page, it is checked whether this email has already made a purchase or not (if there is no purchase), the product is allowed to be purchased and after payment, the details are entered (email values and name or phone number) should be stored in a separate table in the database (that is, product invoice number values, purchase date, payment amount, buyer's email, name, phone number, etc.).
If a purchase was made with the entered email, it will be redirected to a special page, for example error.php

**Some notes:**

1. Is it possible that the buyer does not need to register on the site to buy virtual and downloadable products and just enter his email, name and phone number and then be directed to the payment page?

- The user's e-mail needs to be validated only for the purchase, and there is no need for anything else such as postal code, address, password, etc., because they are not going to register on the site or have a user panel (the buyer only has an e-mail, name and number He enters his phone, then he is directed to the payment page, and after successful payment, he creates and displays the file download link that I explained above).

2. No physical product is sold on this site and no panel or user page is needed for registration etc.

**Optional item:**
I want to use cryptocurrency payment method. If you have a suggestion in this regard that matches my question, please help (preferably an open source plugin).

+

So imagine that I have 4 products in the whole site and each product is going to generate a file like this product but with different personalized codes.

**The entire process of purchasing the product is as follows:**

> Go to the product page -> enter name, phone number and email in three separate fields and then click on buy the product -> go to the payment page -> successful payment -> go to the successful payment screen and generate a text file and display Download link to the buyer (according to the description above)